# Sql-server equivalent of mysql_maketime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to create time from hours and minutes. In mysql there is a 'Maketime' function exactly for that

```
mysql> SELECT MAKETIME(12,15,30);
    -> '12:15:30'
```

What function should I use to do it in sql server?

Comment: what version of SQL Server?

Comment: 2012 but is there nothing like TIMEOFPARTS in previous versions?

Comment: No, that is a new function in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 has `TIMEFROMPARTS`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213398.aspx

Comment: Yes, `TIMEFROMPARTS` and `DATEFROMPARTS` are new in sql server 2012.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I've needed, couldn't find it by myself though.

Answer (score 2):

For earlier versions of SQL Server (pre 2012) you just need to use a combination of `DateAdd()` functions.

```
SELECT DateAdd(hh, 12, DateAdd(mi, 15, DateAdd(ss, 30, 0)))
```

Note that this returns a `datetime` value. If you are using 2008 and upwards then you can simply `Cast()` to `time` if required.

Comment: Actually I'm using 2012 but it is good to know how to do it in previous versions also. Thanks

Comment: definitely helpful for 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

You could

```
dateadd(second, (12 * 3600) + (15 * 60) + 30, cast('00:00:00' as time))
```

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest way to do it in SQL Server 2008 R2 when working with variables / separate valuse for hours/mins/secs

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '20:10:44', 108) -- hh:mm:ss
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp